# Cannot see if my queue is a transaction

Tags: msmq

I'm trying to send a message to a remote queue.

```
  // Send a message to the queue.
        if (myQueue.Transactional)
        {
            var myTransaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
            myTransaction.Begin();
            Message objMessage = new Message();

            objMessage.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;
            objMessage.Body = message;

            myQueue.Send(objMessage, myTransaction);

            myTransaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            Message objMessage = new Message();

            objMessage.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;
            objMessage.Body = message;
            myQueue.Send(message);
        }
```

but I get an exception

```
The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.
```

I assume that my queue name is incorrect or I have a permission error so I enabled the dead letter queue but it's empty. My queue name is "FormatName:Direct=TCP:xx.xxx.xx.xx\private$\Test"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query information about a remote private queue. 
Local queues, yes. Remote public queues, yes, but not with Formatname.